# Script won't run on Solaris

Tags: bash, solaris

I'm trying to make the following script run on `SunOS 5.10 Generic_120011-14 sun4v sparc SUNW`, but I'm having difficulties with adjusting it.

```
#!/bin/bash
DIRECTORY=$1
if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
 if [ -d "$DIRECTORY" ]; then
   find "$DIRECTORY" -mindepth 1 -printf '%y %p\n' | awk '$1=="d"{sub(/.*\//,"&DIR: ")} {gsub(/[^\/]*\//," ")} 1'
 else
   echo "That directory doesn't exist."
   exit 1
 fi
else
 find . -mindepth 1 -printf '%y %p\n' | awk '$1=="d"{sub(/.*\//,"&DIR: ")} {gsub(/[^\/]*\//,"  ")} 1'
fi
```

Command `find` doesn't have `-printf` nor does it have `-mindepth`. Any suggestions what should I use instead?

Comment: does this script run on other operating systems, or is this a solaris specific issue?

Comment: see if the `/usr/xpg4/bin/find` support `printf` . I don't have access to Solaris anymore, so I can't check. If not, you're already post-processing the output with `awk`, so you can build some more formatting into the `awk` side rather than relying on `%y %p\n`.  Good luck.

Comment: @shellter same, I get `/usr/xpg4/bin/find: bad option -printf` and `bad option -mindepth`

Comment: @aprilduck Anything in the man pages for `find` on your system regarding another option similar to `printf` `mindepth`? Perhaps the option naming is slightly different on that version and there is already a similar option installed for an easy fix.

Comment: what version of bash? as well as find?

Comment: @jgr208 Version of bash is 'GNU bash, version 4.2.37(1)-release (sparc-sun-solaris2.10)'. I'm not sure how to get version for find, `man` page has only date, 14 May 2007

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not Solaris specific, the problem is you are using GNU extensions so your script is not portable, i.e. not POSIX.

There are two ways to overcome the issue, either the GNU utilities you need are already installed on your Solaris 10 machine, and you just need to tell your script to use them, or they are not installed and you need to modify your script to use POSIX or at least Solaris standard options and syntax.

- 1. GNU tools

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=$PATH:/usr/sfw/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/csw/bin
DIRECTORY=$1
if [ $# -eq 1 ]; then
 if [ -d "$DIRECTORY" ]; then
   gfind "$DIRECTORY" -mindepth 1 -printf '%y %p\n' | gawk '$1=="d"{sub(/.*\//,"&DIR: ")} {gsub(/[^\/]*\//," ")} 1'
 else
   echo "That directory doesn't exist."
   exit 1
 fi
else
 gfind . -mindepth 1 -printf '%y %p\n' | gawk '$1=="d"{sub(/.*\//,"&DIR: ")} {gsub(/[^\/]*\//,"  ")} 1'
fi
```

- 2. Solaris tools

```
#!/bin/ksh
DIRECTORY=${1:-.}
if [ ! -d "$DIRECTORY" ]; then
  echo "That directory doesn't exist."
  exit 1
fi
find "$DIRECTORY" ! -name "$DIRECTORY" -exec \
   ksh -c 'printf "%c %s\n" $(ls -dl "$1" | cut -c1-1) "$1"' sh {} \; | \
   nawk '$1=="d"{sub(/.*\//,"&DIR: ")} {gsub(/[^\/]*\//," ")} 1'
```